# Macbook Pro, completely broken keyboard, can't login!

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, password, screen, login

I have 15 inch macbook pro and the keyboard recently stopped working completely.  None of the keys work.  I got a wireless apple keyboard, to fix the problem.  The issue is that I need to login in order to set up the external keyboard, and since the keyboard is  broken, I obviously can't login. My trackpad still works though.

Is there a way to login if nothing on my internal keyboard works.  Please note, the answer can't be some sort of reset for which I need to push any keys - I have tried these, and they don't work, because the keyboard doesn't work.

Thanks!!

Comment: Wireless keyboard needs Bluetooth working. Bluetooth is not active until log in is completed. Solution would be to use SUB keyboard, since system does scan for USB device during boot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't setup Bluetooth devices without logging in, USB keyboard is the only way to go. Bring you Macbook to school or work and use one of their keyboards for a minute to logon and pair the Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: well that won't work *now*...

Answer (score 0):

You could login as a guest user, if you've enabled that option. No password necessary!