# How to login when I can't enter my password because "e" key on keyboard doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, login

My "E" key on my keyboard stopped working. The tech says I need to change the keyboard, but for now I just want to use a bluetooth apple keyboard. The problem is I can't connect it without logging in and I can't log in as my password contains an "E"? What can I do to connect the bluetooth keyboard? Everything else works. Keys and mouse plus trackpad.

Answer (score 7):

Try entering <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to bring up the "Accessibility Options" popup window. This window will appear similar to what is shown below.

[image: k0]

Select "Enable Accessibility Keyboard", then click on the "Done" button. The on-screen keyboard should appear, as shown below.

[image: k1]

Use the keyboard to enter the "E" key or the entire password.

Comment: When i try hitting down those keys it says something that sounds like "Voiceover user name on" and switches to a username/password view.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's current Bluetooth keyboard is the [Magic Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Keyboard), and this also allows the keyboard to be connected to your Mac via a supplied Lightning adapter cable.

I would suggest connecting this first in order to be able to pair the keyboard, and then you will be able to log in as usual using the external Bluetooth keyboard afterwards.

You only need any physical keyboard (PC, Mac, anything basically) [to set up your Bluetooth and for emergency use if Bluetooth pairing fails](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158806/) in the future.